# Выполнение скрипта .vbs в тихом режиме из InnoSetup

Tags: vbscript, inno-setup

Имеется скрипт, добавляющий порт в брандмауэр Windows и инсталлятор на InnoSetup, запускающий этот скрипт от имени администратора.

**script.vbs:**

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=Test protocol=TCP localport=5433 action=allow dir=IN"
```

**Запуск в InnoSetup:**

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\script.vbs"; Flags: shellexec runascurrentuser;
```

Как мне запустить скрипт *без всплывающего окна консоли*?

Comment: Это же все есть в документации. Добавьте флаг `runhidden`.

Comment: @Yaant, Окно консоли все-равно появляется на миг.

Comment: Хм. А если обойтись без промежуточного .vbs файла и, соответственно, флага `shellexec`, и запускать непосредственно `netsh` с нужными параметрами?

Comment: @Yaant, В будущем необходимо будет писать другие команды на vbs. Так что нужно решение данной проблемы без компромиссов.

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать вместо использования флага `shellexec` вызывать непосредственно `wscript.exe` c параметрами. Или лучше, `cscript.exe`, ибо есть подозрение, что окно открывает сам `wscript.exe`

Comment: @Yaant, `Filename: "cscript.exe"; Parameters: "{tmp}\script.vbs //B"; Flags:runascurrentuser;` теперь на миг появляются два окна

Comment: Ну так `runhidden`-то все равно нужен. И еще стоит попробовать `exec` вместо `run`. Кстати, может оказаться, что для решения проблемы будет достаточно использовать `exec` и в исходном варианте.

Answer (score 3):

Помогло такое решение:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\script.vbs"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion; AfterInstall: ExecScript;

[Code]
procedure ExecScript;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('cscript.exe'), 'script.vbs', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Failed to execute script.vbs file' + #13#10 + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Больше никаких всплывающих окон консоли. Спасибо @Yaant за ценные комментарии.